# How can we deploy newer versions of code on the fly for Google Cloud Functions code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to intergrate other GCP Platforms services with cloud function which will fuflill our needs for our requirements ?

Comment: What are those needs? By "deploy newer versions of code on the fly", are you referring to continuous integration? If that's the case you should be looking at using [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) and not Cloud Functions

Comment: I want to know it for Cloud functions code .I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your goal here is to update your code running on Cloud Functions - please correct me if I'm wrong, or if this doesn't help.

**Via Cloud Build**

As Guillermo said, you can use Cloud Build to automatically deploy changes to your Cloud Functions code. See [this page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing#continuous_testing_and_deployment) for information on how to integrate Cloud Functions with Cloud Build (and optionally, a version control system of your choice).

**Via an API**

If you're looking to update your Cloud Functions code *programmatically*, take a look at the [`projects.locations.functions.create`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/create) API call.

Hope this helps!